# Merging multiple migration files into one migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have 4 migration files on the local environment. I have deployed this app on the development server (so the 4 migration have affected the development server database). I have not deployed these migrations in the production server.

All the 4 migrations are related and I want to merge them inside a single migration file.

This is my approach.

- Manually delete the last 3 migration files and copy their content into the first file.
- Deploy the app again on the development server

My doubts:

- Is it enough to manually delete the files?
- Also the migrations has already ran on development server so will the development server rerun the first migration file or will it actually require do that?

This is the migration file (if required):

```
change_column :slots, :notes, :text
add_column :slots, :notestext, :text
Slot.update_all('notestext=notes')
remove_column :slots, :notes
rename_column :slots, :notestext, :notes
```

Comment: Why bother? Migrations are just supposed to be run and then deleted.

Answer (score 4):

There should be no issue in keeping four migration files, still if you want to merge the migration files into one then first `rollback` the migrations which will delete all your data from the database and then follow your approach to copy everything to one file and re run the migrations.

Running `rollback` is necessary because Rails will never run the migration it has already ran, Rails tracks this using `schema_migrations` table in database where it stores the version of migration it has already ran. Also the schema.rb file has the latest version of migration it has ran. So keep things synchronized `rollback` the migrations you have already ran and re run them once changed.

Also if you create a new migration combining all the four then it will give exception on database as the tables already exists. And if you copy all the four in old migration then your `schema_migrations` table would have some version number which has no file associated with it and running `rake db:migrate:status` will give output something like this:

```
   up     20191117112500  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20191117112930  ********** NO FILE **********
```

So it is better to rollback things and re run the migrations which will keep all things synchronized. To rollback four migrations you can do like this:

```
rails db:rollback STEP=4
```

Or you can also check the current status of the migrations and rollback them one by one like this:

```
rails db:migration:status
rails db:migration:down VERSION=<version_number>
```

You can also run the `rails db:rollback` command four times which will do the job.

**Beware:** This will delete all your existing data which you have in the database